# CUDA - Synchronous Threads -> Wait until first in is finish with writing

Tags: memory, cuda, synchronous

I am trying to do the following (simplify): **Please read the edit section!**

```
__shared__ int currentPos = 0;
__global__ myThreadedFunction(float *int, float *out)
{
    // do calculations with in values
    ...

    // now first thread reach this:
    //suspend other threads up here

    out += currentPos;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        *(currentPos++) =  calculation[i];
    }
    currentPos +=  size;

    // now thread is finish, other threads can
    // go on with writing
}
```

So how do I suspend threads before writing to same memory?  I cannot write concurrently, because I do not know the size of each calculatet array (calculation[i] - size).

I know there is *syncthreads* and *threadfence* but I don´t know how I must use them right for this problem.

**Edit:**
What I want to do is:

I have got 2 threads (just for example).
Each thread is calculating with the float *in a new array.

Thread 1 calculated:
{ 1, 3, 2, 4 }

Thread 2 calculated:
{ 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4 }

The size of these arrays is known after the calculation.
Now I want to write these arrays in the float *out.

It is not necessary for me, if first thread 1 or thread 2 is writing. The output could be:
* { 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4 } or { 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4} *

So how to calculate the positions of the output array?

I don´t want to use a fixed "array size" so that the output would be:
* { 1, 3, 2, 4, ?, ?, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4 } *

I think I could us a shared variable POSITION for the next writing position.

Thread 1 reach the writing point (after calculation the new array).
Thread 1 write in shared variable POSITION his array size (4).

While Thread 1 is now writing his temp-array to the output array,
thread 2 reads the variable POSITION and add his tmp. array size (6) to this variable and start writing
at the position where thread 1 ends

If there would be a thread 3, he would also read POSITION, add his array size and writing into the ouput, where thread 2 ends

So anyone a idea?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There might be a better way to solve your problem... But to do what you want, simply calculate thread ID within the block and put the code inside a condition if(threadInBlock == 0) {...}

Comment: It seems each of your threads writes to a different position of `out[]`. Why they can not write concurrently?

Comment: The problem is, I don´t know the size of the calculatetd array.
If I have:
Thread 1: 1, 2, 3, 4
Thread 2: 4, 5

In out should be written:
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5

Comment: So why don't you have 6 threads? Because if thread 2 works only after thread 1 finishes, then it's actually serial, not parallel. Try to describe your problem a bit more detailed...

Comment: I can´t seperate these calculation in 6 threads. I am calculate a new array, not only a number. The calculation is parallel but the writing should be serial after they reach the "writing point".

Comment: Suggestion 1: you may want to map each element of `out[]` to a thread to avoid this situation. Suggestion 2: calculate the writing position for each thread first. It can be done by prefix_sum of the sequence `size` from each thread.

Comment: First suggestion: No, it think, it would not work for my problem (complexer). Second suggestion: Calculation the writing position first? Just after I am reaching the writing point (after the calculation of my new subarray) I know the size. Is there no way to suspend threads inside an global function like a query or so?

Comment: If the array is big, prefix scan is a good idea, it would be faster to compute position first and then write in parallel. But if you don't want to do that, just use conditions. Compute thread index and and write to the output one by one.. you don't need to 'suspend' other threads...

Comment: Prefix scan or compute thread index? How? Do you can explain what you mean? I have edit a better example again, hope that helps. Thank you all for your replay btw! I hate to use comments for such a conversation.. sorry.

Comment: Also you need `__device__ pos;` instead of `__shared__ pos;` if you have multiple blocks in your grid.

Comment: one more question.. How do you launch your kernel? What block and grid dimension do you use?

Comment: I don´t know for what you need it for. I want to do an array expanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204562/thrust-how-to-use-my-array-data-model

So in this case I have 1 block with n threads.
n is the count of subarrays in the secound array

Comment: I've edited by answer. It now works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually how you would do a concurrent output using an shared array to store the indexes for each thread.

```
__global__ myThreadedFunction(float *int, float *out)
{

    __shared__ index[blockDim.x];//replace the size with an constant
    // do calculations with in values
    ...



    index[tid] = size;// assuming size is the size of the array you output
    //you could do a reduction on this for loop for better performance.
    for(int i = 1; i < blockDim.x; ++i) {
        __syncthreads();
        if(tid == i) {
            index[tid] += index[tid-1];
        }
    }
    int startposition = index[tid] - size; // you want to start at the start, not where the index ends

    //do your output for all threads concurrently where startposition is the first index you output to

}
```

So what you do is assign `index[tid]` to the size you want to output, where `tid` is the thread index `threadIdx.x`, then do a summation uppwards the array(increasing index), and then finally `index[tid]` is the offset starting index in your output array from thread 0. The summation could easily be done using reduction.

Comment: Reply deleted?? You could extend my design to include a global index array such `gindex[blockIdx.x] = index[blockDim.x-1]` and the global offset is the sum of global indexes less than `blockIdx.x`

Answer (score 0):

This code works as you expected. It concurrently read the `input[]`. For each input element
`size`, it write `size` for `size` times to `result` in the order as stored in `input[]`.

Please note the writing procedure may take much longer than do this on CPU. Since you've already know the size of data for each thread to write, you may want to use [parallel prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) to calculate the writing postion for each thread first, and then write the data concurrently.

See [Memory Fence Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) for more info about `__threadfence()` used in the code.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>

volatile __device__ int count = 0;
volatile __device__ int pos = 0;
__global__ void serial(const float* input, const int N, float* result)
{
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    //parallel part
    int size = (int) input[id];

    //serial output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int localcount = count;
        if (localcount == id)
        {
            int localpos = pos;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                result[localpos + j] = (float) j + 1;
            }
            pos = localpos + size;
            count = localcount + 1;
            __threadfence();
        }
        while (count == localcount)
        {
            __syncthreads();
        };

    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 6;
    thrust::device_vector<float> input(
            thrust::counting_iterator<float>(1),
            thrust::counting_iterator<float>(1) + N);

    thrust::device_vector<float> result(N * (N + 1) / 2);
    serial<<<2, 3>>>(
            thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&input[0]),
            N,
            thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&result[0]));

    thrust::copy(
            result.begin(), result.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;

}
```

output as expected:

```
1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: putting a `__syncthreads()` inside your spin-lock would be beneficial as it would block warps waiting, and thus free up resources. But this method can easily lead to a deadlock if block 1 is scheduled to be run before block 0 and takes up all resources, thus not allowing block 0 to be run to increment count.

Comment: @ks6g10 I think `__syncthreads()` won't sync between different blocks. It works only within one block.

Comment: @ks6g10 you are right it could be a deadlock, if blocks are not scheduled by the order. But I think that won't be fixed by `__syncthreads()`. Maybe nothing can fix it ...

Comment: Will not work between blocks, but within blocks, if you have 256(8 warps) threads within each block, that means you can sync-block 7 warps for the active block(reducing preassure), and iteratively all the remaining warps for all the other blocks, ofc when all warps in an inactive block converge, they will again do a check on the count, sync check sync... but it will probably reduce some pressure of the SM and the instruction scheduler.

Comment: The only way to do it properly(multiple blocks) and to assure there is data consistency and no deadlock is to store everything in block-wise arrays and then launch a second kernel to clean up everything.